# azure website deployment vs azure cloud services deployment

Tags: sql, azure, azure-web-roles

I have a website which has azure sql federations in back end. Everything works fine if it is deployed as website but as soon as it is deployed as cloud services it breaks down.

Can some one point out me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you did not configure your sql database to allow requests for all services inside Windows Azure Datacenters.

[image]